# SQL Count and selecting other fields

Tags: sql, count, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know very basic but getting myself confused. I just want to add a column at the end that shows the count of the unique_key

```
select unique_key , date_trunc('month',enrollment_date::date) date_enrolled,
enrollment_reason, count(unique_key)
from table1
group by unique_key;
```

I get this error:

```
SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 42 'unique_key' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause.
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Count is an aggregate function. All non-aggregate columns in your select need to be included in the Group By clause.

Comment: @JPortillo - this was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run that, I get the error `...'enrollment_date' in select clause is neither an aggregate...` It's weird that it's erroring on the unique_key.

But I think what's happening is that you are trying to show the date and enrollment reason in your select, but you haven't grouped by those. The query you have is trying to get all of the rows for one `unique_key`, but then it doesn't know which `enrollment_reason` to return, for example. Even if every record with a specific `unique_key` has the same `enrollment_reason`, the query optimizer doesn't know that, so it doesn't make that assumption.

Generally, to fix this you should group by everything in your select clause that isn't an aggregate.

```
select unique_key , date_trunc('month',enrollment_date::date) date_enrolled, 
enrollment_reason, count(unique_key)
from table1
group by unique_key, date_enrolled, enrollment_reason;
```

Another approach is to put those attributes in an aggregate. This works well if you know that the column is always the same, or you don't care which result you get for that column. Max is a common choice for this.

```
select unique_key,
  max(date_trunc('month',enrollment_date::date)) date_enrolled, 
  max(enrollment_reason),
  count(unique_key)
from table1
group by unique_key, date_enrolled, enrollment_reason;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend:

```
select date_trunc('month',enrollment_date::date) as date_enrolled,
       enrollment_reason, count(*)
from table1
group by date_trunc('month',enrollment_date::date), enrollment_reason;
```

Comment: snowflake allows for the `GROUP BY` to refer to the alias name, thus `GROUP BY date_enrolled, enrollment_reason` is valid, and more readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use derived table to achieve this. you need to have aggregate functions for GROUP BY clause.

```
select unique_key, count(date_enrolled)
from
(select unique_key , date_trunc('month',enrollment_date::date) date_enrolled,
enrollment_reason
from table1) as t
group by unique_key;
```